# Replace keys and values in array

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays:

```
<?php
    $c = array('john' => 34,'mary'=>22,'rita'=>19);
    $d = array('malone' => 43);
?>
```

How do I go about changing the key `mary` and merging the value of `$d` into `$c`? My apologies if this sounds like a dumb question but I really don't know how and I have searched on-line to no solution.

Comment: I don't know if there is something as a "second key" in an associative array. The order of keys is arbitrary.

Comment: use `array_push($d, $c['mary']);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `unset()` to remove a key from an array and then concatenate the two arrays as follows:

```
<?php
    $c = array('john' => 34,'mary'=>22,'rita'=>19);
    $d = array('malone' => 43);
    unset($c['mary']);
    $c += $d;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

What I did to solve this:

```
$newkey =array('jane'=>1);
unset($c['mary']);
$e = array_merge($c,$newkey);
print_r($e);
```

Thanks though.